# CleanupRecodeProperties:3604 Error Message Meaning

Tags: swift, image-processing, swiftui, core-graphics, core-foundation

I am using the function below, from Apple Core Graphics (CGImage).

`CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(idst, isrc, index, properties)`

Whenever I use it, it appears to run correctly, but it still outputs the following error message.

`CleanupRecodeProperties:3604: IIOReadPlugin::CleanupRecodeProperties:  top: 1  tiff: 1`

I have searched Google and StackOverflow for this error message (and smaller parts of it) and have not been able to find anything. I can't find its meaning in the Core Graphics documentation either.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me understand what it means.

Comment: Is this a separate question from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632124/writing-exposure-bias-isnt-returning-the-expected-result) on the same message?

Comment: The error message is included in my previous question, but I wasn't sure if the issue depended on it. You're correct that I am asking about it since I hope it might help me solve my previous problem myself though. Do you know what could be going on?

Comment: It looks like a benign debug message.

Comment: Is there any way I can find out more about what this means? Is there more in-depth documentation?